# Attempting to Hash known data, but not allow user to recreate hash

Tags: cryptography

I have a situation where my application creates a hash based on it's serial number(for example: A1C2-E3G-4I5K). The serial is known to the user. The hash will also be known to the user. What is the best strategy to hash the data while making it impossible/extremely difficult for the user to create the hash themselves?

I am using the hash as a way of showing that an action has taken place on the remote application.

I have thought about private Key encryption, but it could be possible for the user to get hold of the private key themselves.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It sounds like something related to software licensing - if so, you may find this is a solved problem (with open source libraries to boot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into a [Keyed-HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code). Basicly you create a lets say SHA-256 hash on your value plus a secret key, only known to your application. With that assumption user will not be able to create valid hash for his own.

Comment: Thanks alot, much better than my homegrown hack!

Answer (score 0):

You could try "salting" the serial number before hashing it
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29

Comment: how would I know what salt to use when recreating the hash? Or are you suggesting a non random salt?

Comment: a salt/iv wouldn't work, since it's not secret. You need a key, not an iv.